# Dagesh for adornment

Tags: mesorah-tradition, beshalach, parashas-shemos, vowels-nekudot

On *Sh'mos* 2:3 and 15:17, *Minchas Shay* notes that הַצְּפִינוֹ and מִקְּדָשׁ have a *dagesh* in their respective second letters "for adornment (*tif'eres*)".

1. 1. Is this aural or visual adornment?
   2. How/Why is the presence of the *dagesh* considered an adornment?
2. Why are these words, specifically, adorned?

Comment: This is called 'euphonic dagesh' in English, if that helps. I think it's definitely 'aural' adornment, dagesh le-tif'eret _haqri'a_.

Comment: @paquda, more specifically, it's sometimes called _dagesh forte dirimens_, apparently.

Answer (score 3):

A shewa naʿ generally reflects a reduced vowel. The words you cite have a shewa naʿ where no originally short vowel existed. For example, we find מִקְדָּשׁ but in Shemot 15:17 we have מִקְּדָֿשׁ. We also get an unexpected dagesh in הַצְּפִֿינוֹ (as you note, in Shemot 2:3) and מַמְּגֻֿרוֹת (Joel  1:17).

Blau believes that this dagesh indicates that the shewa is naʿ, and not gemination. He does not suggest a reason for the appearance of the anomalous dagesh.

He states the phenomenon "is quite rare when the letter following the šwa is not a *bgdkpt* letter, e.g., יִקְּהַת ‘the obedience(?) of’, pronounced *yiqəhat* Gen 49:1" (Blau, Phonology & Morphology of Biblical Hebrew, p. 114).

---

I am not convinced that the letter with the dagesh is not geminated; at least, not at the time of the Masoretes. The University of Michigan manuscript, for example, has the form מִקֲּדָשׁ (and not מִקֲֿדָשׁ) (Shemot 15:17), which apparently geminates the qof. As Double AA commented, a hatef would seem to be the natural choice to make explicit that a shewa is naʿ without gemination.

Khan appears to agree. He writes:

> Sometimes the preceding consonant is geminated, e.g., מִקְּדָ֕שׁ [miqqaˈðɔː∫] ‘sanctuary’ (Exod. 15.17 < מִקְדָּשׁ [miqdɔː∫]), עִקְּב֥וֹת [ʕiqqaˈvoːχ] ‘footprints of’ (Psa. 89.52 < עִקְבוֹת [ʕiqvoːχ]), מַמְּרֹרִֽים [mammaʀoːˈʀiːm] ‘bitterness’ (Job 9.18 < מַמְרֹרִים [mammaʀoːʀiːm) (*Epenthesis: Biblical Hebrew*, Encyclopedia of Hebrew Language and Linguistics)

Comment: How did those /a/s get in there in the Khan transcriptions? Does he really hold that is the pronunciation of _sh'va_? As in, no _chatuf_ written, but one is pronounced?

Comment: @WAF That is correct. It is well known that in Tiberian tradition a shewa naʿ before any letter (except אהחי״ע) was pronounced as a hatef patach.